# What are the potentials at front and back of inductor when primary DC supply is disconnected in LR circuit?

Tags: dc, inductance, back-emf

I have been learning the basics of inductors in simple LR circuits with DC currents. I think I get most of it but I am a bit unclear about the secondary EMF produced by the inductor after the primary supply is disconnected. In particular I am unsure about the actual electric potentials at the ends of the inductor just after the primary battery supply has been disconnected.

In the QUCS (v. 0.0.19) transient simulation image below, the maximum voltage drop across the inductor (L1), at time > 0.150 s is about -5 V (see the graph for voltage probe PR2). (I would like to plot the value of potential around the circuit at different times - but I have not found a way to do this with QUCS).

[image: Figure 1]

I assume that this means the potential at the front is 0 V and at the back it is about +5 V. This would make sense to me in that the inductor subsequently acts like a dying battery - pushing a dwindling current around the secondary loop in a clockwise direction.

But I am also aware that the -5 V voltage drop across the inductor could also be caused by potentials of -5 V at the front and 0 V at the end. It seems to me that scenario would also drive a current around the secondary loop in the clockwise direction.

So my question is: which of these two scenarios is correct?

**Update after Question Answered**

Following the receommendation by u/RussellH I probed the potentials at points A,B,C,D with the following (QUCS) graphical results (below).  I also plotted (in Excel)(further below) the profile of Potential vs. X (relative position along the section of the circuit containing R1,L1,R2).

[image: QUCS plot of Potentials and Voltage Drops]

[image: Excel plot of Potential P profiles along X at different times]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *So my question is which of these two scenarios is correct?*

Neither.

- At the instant that S3 shorts, there is **still** 1 amp flowing through L1, R1 and R2.
- Given that R1 (2.5 Ω) is grounded to 0 volts by S3, the top node of R1 has to be at -2.5 volts.
- I think you can work out the other voltage now.

Comment: Ha! I should have known not to exclude other options!.  Thanks for the advice. I deduce that the potentials (relative to 0V at ground) at t ~ 0.150 s are A:0V, B:-2.5V, C:+2.5V and D:0V (ignoring the small changes in potential along the wires necessary to get the electrons to flow along the wires.)

Comment: @steveOw Correct and, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had upvoted you already but that was someone else.  I am currently looking at the other answers before Accepting the best.  As they are all good I'd normally accept the first one - but they are now all time-stamped "7 hours ago"!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the zero voltage reference is. If ground is the reference, then the voltage to the left of the inductor is -2.5 V set by the current through R1 just after S3 closed. The voltage on the right is +2.5V set by the current through R2. Both voltages then decay exponentially to zero.

You can test this by using the sim probes from the left side and right side of the inductor to ground.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.  I understand the potential pattern now. Also thanks for pointing out that in QUCs I can simply connect one leg of a probe to ground to measure potential relative to ground.

Answer (score 2):

Neither case is correct. Your inductor sits between two 2.5ohm resistors with respect to ground. At steady-state current flow, your only impedance is 5 ohms (2 x 2.5ohms) which amounts to 1A in the loop. Opening the battery and closing S3, the current is still 1A at this moment. Using ground as the reference, you are dropping 2.5V per resistor (1A*2.5ohms).

So from ground (0V), R1 is going to be -2.5V because the inductor is sinking current from there. And from symmetry (and math), R2 will be at +2.5V WRT ground.

In other words, the R1-L1 junction sits at -2.5V and the L1-R2 junction sits at +2.5 giving a potential difference of 5V (the battery voltage). From there, the transient analysis is simply a first-order decay of current through the circuit and voltages dropped across the elements.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. I'm OK with understanding the exponential decay formulae.  I'm not sure what "sinking current from there" means. But I now understand the pattern of potential thanks to your answer and the 2 others.